# mysql table design, divide or all in one table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have table house

```
CREATE TABLE `house` 
   `idhouse` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `type` mediumint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `address` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `county` varchar(5) ...
```

Now, I have the ads functionality. So want to bring the house into ads

Method 1 (directly add columns for adds)

```
CREATE TABLE `house` 
   `idhouse` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `type` mediumint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `address` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `county` varchar(5) ...
   `ad_type` mediumint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ad_urgency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
   `ad_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Method 2 (normalization, split it into table Ads)

```
CREATE TABLE `house` 
   `idhouse` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `type` mediumint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `address` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `county` varchar(5) ...

CREATE TABLE `Ads` 
   `idAds` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `idhouse` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
   `ad_type` mediumint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ad_urgency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
   `ad_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

- I'll do more SELECT (90%) operations instead of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (10%)
- SELECT operations will **ALL** be based on variables such **ad_type, ad_urgency,**  and **ad_status.**
- I'm taking consideration of performance a lot.

Which method should I use ? 
Is using method 1 (SELECT without joining) is faster than method 2 (SELECT with joining) ? 
If faster, by how much ? A lot ?

Comment: Your second method is necessary if you have multiple ads per house. If not, go for the first method, since it will always be faster if you need columns from both tables.

Comment: how many records are we talking here?

Comment: should be only 10k records at most, I think.

Comment: i think go for first method. Although i dont think you are going to gain a lot if you chose either method. 10K records are not much.

Comment: @AshReva Until how many records actually that I should pay attention to the normalization ?

Comment: @HendryH. i am not real database guy but from my experience i said that 10K records are not much. If it starts to grow beyond 100K then you may feel performance issues.

Comment: @HendryH. Also i will be really interested to know if you get any performance benefit with 10K record using both the technique. I really favour normalisation though. Will it be possible for you to test with both techniques?

Comment: Haha.. I have the same interest with you! I'll do this when I got time I guess ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization has alot of advantages.

- It helps you avoid redundancies.
- It makes your database structure flexible.
- It helps you avoid anomalies.
- Complex queries are usually easier.
- It minimizes your data

...and a few more.

The speed of queries cannot be easily determined by the data structure alone, it is affected by many different aspects like database configuration, server hardware, indexing, data load and much more.

But since less data usually means faster queries (with or without joins): Go for the normalzied approach. The database admin taking the system over will thank you.

Comment: I actually prefer the normalization way, but sometimes concerned a little about performance and extra coding.

Comment: If you want a quick&dirty solution, maybe. But in almost any case a good - and normalized - table design is worth the extra coding.